# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/AnalysisHelper while writing delta-lake into s3 storage

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, delta-lake

I tried to convert some pickle file in s3 into delta lake. The way I did this is using boto to load the data and convert to spark dataframe then use data.write.format('delta').save(s3_path)

But when I tried to save this data into s3. It raised me this error. I google for a long time, but delta-lake is quite new. There is little discussion.

Since the error shows java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/AnalysisHelper, I checked the source code of spark github. The actuall path of AnalysisHelper is spark/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/. I am not sure if this is the root of the error.

```py
def test_pyspark_fun():

    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('abc').getOrCreate()
    data = spark.range(0, 5)
    spark.read.format("delta")
    print("writing...")
    data.write.format("delta").save("s3a://bucket/folder/delta_lake_test_folder")
    print("writing done...")
```

I run with command

```
spark-submit --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.11:0.1.0,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3 pyspark_script.py
```

Here is the error message

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o40.save.
: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/AnalysisHelper$
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2261)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4000)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4789)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.apply(DeltaLog.scala:721)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.forTable(DeltaLog.scala:653)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource.createRelation(DeltaDataSource.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:225)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/AnalysisHelper$
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$$anon$3$$anonfun$call$1.apply(DeltaLog.scala:724)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$$anon$3$$anonfun$call$1.apply(DeltaLog.scala:724)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksLogging$class.recordOperation(DatabricksLogging.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.recordOperation(DeltaLog.scala:626)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging$class.recordDeltaOperation(DeltaLogging.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$.recordDeltaOperation(DeltaLog.scala:626)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$$anon$3.call(DeltaLog.scala:723)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog$$anon$3.call(DeltaLog.scala:721)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4792)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3599)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2379)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2342)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2257)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 48 more
```

Hope someone can help me out. Or anyone knows any other way to write delta-lake folder into s3. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Now delta lake support connecting s3 directly. Check [here](https://docs.delta.io/0.2.0/delta-storage.html).

Comment: review your libraries in class path this is clearly classpath issue. spark libraries are not there in classpath via your spark submit or maven or sbt etc...

Answer (score 3):

What is your Spark version? org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/AnalysisHelper came about in 2.4.0. If you are using an older version, you will have this issue.

In 2.4.0
https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/v2.4.0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical

In 2.3.3
https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/v2.3.3/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical

Please also note that [Delta Lake currently requires Apache Spark 2.4.2](https://github.com/delta-io/delta#compatibility-with-apache-spark-versions).

Comment: @zhen404 `Delta Lake currently requires Apache Spark 2.4.2.` see https://github.com/delta-io/delta#compatibility-with-apache-spark-versions

Comment: Thanks! @zsxwing. Now I use 2.4.3. It works now. Looking forward to more features supported by delta lake